Is the problem of checking whether the intersection of any two given CFL is CFL?
Is the following problem decidable. "Given 2 CFL, $L_1$ and $L_2$. Is $L_1 \cap L_2$ a CFL?"
CFL is an abbreviation for "Context Free Language".

This is not decidable.
We can use the fact that it is undecidable whether $L_1\cap L_2=\varnothing$ for context-free languages $L_1,L_2$.
Take two (fixed) context-free languages $K_1,K_2$ such that $K_1\cap K_2$ is not context-free. Also take a symbol $\#$ which is not in the alphabet of any of the four languages.
Languages $L_1\cdot \# \cdot K_1$ and $L_2\cdot \# \cdot K_2$ are context-free.
Their intersection $(L_1\cdot \# \cdot K_1) \cap  (L_2\cdot \# \cdot K_2)$ equals  $(L_1 \cap L_2) \cdot \# \cdot (K_1\cap K_2)$.
This intersection is either empty and context-free (when $L_1\cap L_2 =\varnothing$) or it is not context-free (otherwise).
Deciding when one intersection is context-free is equivalent to deciding whether to other intersection is empty. Which we can't.

This result as well as its proof, are very similar to Greibach's Theorem about undecidablity of some property for a class of languages. Unfortunately I could not easily demonstrate Greibach is applicable here. So I reused the underlying idea of that proof.
